# URL rewriting doesn't work when web-site is accessed via alias directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a web-site in the directory d:\www\mysite on my local computer.

Then url http://localhost/mysite/index.php correctly retrieves my file which is located in d:\www\mysite\index.php

My issue is with the URL rewriting in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule . /front-controller.php [L]
```

I get this response:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@dominio.org to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

This is my apache conf

```
Alias /debian /mnt/www

<Directory /mnt/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does mod_rewrite installed and enabled? Does mod_alias installed and enabled? Does php have any open_basedir rules? Also read [these answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161198/rewrite-an-alias-directory+) too.

Comment: Check your Apache error log, it will tell you exactly what the problem is and what is causing the error.